# Rule Engine for sport hall management

Tags: php, jsp, liferay, drools, rule-engine

I want to build a web application which contains a generator for a sports hall schedule. Our sport club has a sports hall. It could be devided into 3 parts. Every branch of our club has its own days and times. For scheduling it is very important to define rules like "Time ranges", "possible days", "available equipement in a special part of the hall", "required space", etc...

My question: Is PHP the right basic for such a portal or should I use JSP (e.g. Liferay)? Are there any useful rule engines? I know Drools but this is just for Java.

Other features the portal should contains: forum, calendar (there is no free one for JSP), ticket system, notifications, statistics, ...

Many thanks

Comment: I would like to develop the whole portal with JSP. But I see that Java-Hosting (i.e. Liferay) needs much RAM (2-4 GB) and could be very expensive. But could PHP to slow? Developing in completely in Java could be easier and faster, or?

Comment: Would Wordpress and a bunch of plugins suffice?

Comment: I use Drools planner to generate duty rosters from a PHP application. The PHP application creates a temp file, calls the Drools subprocess which blocks for 10 seconds and reads the output temp file.

Comment: @aitchnyu so you combine both technologies, Java and PHP?

Comment: There is no correct answer to this question - it all depends on your experience, willingness to learn and adapt to new environments. You'll have to face to create or work around the missing features for yourself, no matter with which environment you start. Be aware that you not only need development- but also hosting-knowledge in the solution that you ultimately choose, to keep the installation secure and up to date.

Comment: @Vivid, just loosely coupled. The Java program just deals with temp files. The PHP script provides them and runs the solver program as a subprocess.

Comment: You can also create a long-running drools planner `Solution` object in any java program (maybe even a web application). Disclosure: not at all experienced in such things! The inventor himself, Geoffrey DeSmet is around on StackOverflow to help with Drools Planner stuff.

Comment: The alternative would be a java desktop application which runs local. And this application will export a XML-File, DB-File or something like this. I would use this generator just twice a year or so. But I need the export on my web portal.

Answer (score 1):

You should go for Liferay, several advantages

1. Open Source
2. Server Agnostic
3. Bundled ready made portlets (message board, blog, wiki, announcement, web content, calendar, user management, administration)
4. Multiple portal instance support within single server
5. Multiple site support within one portal instance
6. Strong community (see liferay community link on liferay.com
7. Theme support, color scheme support within theme
8. User import/export with other system, NTLM, CAS, auto login builtin feature
9. Many portlet bridges available (struts, spring, MVC)

And apart from all, anything available in Java, can be hooked using J2EE technology and can be exposed as portlets.

Hope this helps

Comment: Have a look at http://www.liferay.com/products/liferay-portal/features/portal for more details

Comment: I tested Liferay. But it needs much RAM. I need a VServer with 2GB in minimum. I don't know if Liferay needs more RAM if I will have for example 500 users or 15 different organizations.

Comment: There is no Free calendar portlet for Liferay. Only the Build-in calendar with no interaction. Or the vaadin calendar for 150 dollars.

Comment: Calendar portlet is available in Liferay. Since Liferary is open source and it provides sdk, you can integrate any system with it and use that calendar on your own way. Also it supports event import/export with standard formats

Comment: you are right. But I want a calendar like the one from vaadin which supports drag&drop, etc. The calendar portlet isn't instanceable so I use one portlet for everybody. But I want differ the calendar between organizations. One organization needs one column per day, the other organization need 2 oder 4 columns per day in the weekly view.

Comment: Yup, I agree, Liferay supports personalization, you can create different pages for different organization and the calendar instance will be totally different per organization. Great value comes with great responsibility! power of open source :)